# Android programming style

Tags: android

I've been coding for my Android phone lately, and i've been wondering... is this Intent class supposed to outline a new programming style?

I've been suspecting the API design discourages MVC: Intents are the main way to interact with all user-related objects (Activities, Services, Other apps...).

Is my train of thought right? Should is stick to "contaminating" Activities with business logic?

I have been reading the android developers site and no particular coding style is encouraged though.

Comment: I just think it's a way to keep it simple. real simple.

Comment: @Alex I may not have phrased it as a question, but it indeed is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a lot of the following ideas I took from this [OReilly book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449389694).  This is just whats worked best for me.

As far as architecture goes, its helped me to think of Android's UI as a [Page Controller](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/pageController.html) pattern - I found it to be similar to .Net Web Forms actually.  So yes, it does fit with MVC (at least the Page Controller flavor of it).  An Activity is your controller, you typically store your view in XML, and you can build out your Model however you like.

You see a lot of web-ish ideas in Android.  Intents are a lot like HTTP, or more generally REST.  Intents have a 'noun' that says what they are concerned with (can be explicit class declaration ie: go to a specific Activity, or can be more implicit using Intent Filters), the Action is a lot like an HTTP verb (Get, Post, etc), a Bundle is a lot like a list of query string parameters or payload...etc.

And similar to a web page, you want an Activity to be able to take care of itself.  What I mean is, you don't want to pass around some big serialized object from activity to activity, its a lot cleaner/resilient/reliable to just pass the id of the a given record to the next Activity and let that activity grab the record with that id from the db (ContentProvider, some other persistent source...).  Activities are also meant to be loosely coupled, and you're supposed to be able to navigate to one from various paths, it also makes them more re-usable.  Thus, allowing the callers of an Activity to simply provide a recordId is a lot easier then the Activity expecting its consumer to have provided a large serialized object.

Bottom line - no, you don't need to contaminate Activities with Business Logic, tuck that stuff away in an application layer, or a gateway or something like that.  As for persistence, the ContentProvider interface is pretty well designed - I like it alot.  It also continues the Android RESTful theme, accessing content via URLs and verbs (query, delete, update, insert).

Comment: Really liking this answer, will read that book as well. O'Reilly books are awesome. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't entirely clear, because you seem to be confusing coding *style* with program *architecture*.

In my mind, Android really changes nothing in terms of coding style.  Your coding style from Java will still work fine, and most Android apps look very similar to other apps.  In the abstract, there are some things that you might want to do in Android you don't do as much in other languages, [see the Android guide for details.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html)  The basic idea is: memory is limited, don't use it if you don't have to.

As far as whole program architecture goes, yes, the Android style is highly based around the message passing (through Intent objects) style.  The way you react to GUI events *within* an Activity is still largely the same: you use event handlers to react to events like button presses, etc... But the platform is strongly centered around designing apps using different components (Activities, Services, BroadcastReceivers, etc...) and Intents to communicate between them.  While Intents provide a flexible way of exchanging data between components, you still shouldn't be passing massive amounts of data within Intents, instead you should put those kinds of things in a ContentProvider or something similar.

Comment: I may be missing the point... to be specific, i need to bind to a service, and i'd really like to add in a controller should i change my mind and re-use the layouts or the service itself for other purposes. Seeing as the controller can't push Activities into the view all by itself (it needs a context anyways), this pattern is kind of broken and the burden has to be placed on the service and all the actvities to coordinate themselves... is this to be expected?

Answer (score 1):

Sending and receiving intends is much like sending and registering (similar to a publish-subscribe channel) for command messages (e.g. in a distributed enterprise application, and this is about architecture, not style). This pattern helps designing a loosely coupled system of interacting applications.
I cannot remember having seen a similar architecture before used for the interaction of components and applications on a single computer but it helps to design application using other applications to easily build an ecosystem of features/components.

Comment: So if i am getting it right, you are saying Intents are service contracts? A looks for a functionality and starts an intent. B implements such intent so Android calls B to provide A's requirements?

Comment: Basically yes, but there is no information about the provided service but the name of the action. The contract is not enforced and there is no security policy associated with it.